# jquery repeater row click not firing

Tags: jquery, repeater

I have a repeater and i change the color of row on mouseover which works fine.
I also want to pick the repeater row values on click function but the click function doesn't fire. I've tried adding breakpoints and debugging but the debugger doesn't hit the breakpoint at all and the code never gets executed. No errors registered .
my code is like below. I have 'Repeater_selectRow' in the included .js file . I moved the function on page but it doesn't fire. Is there another way of attaching click function to row  or am I missing anything?

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptResults" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div>
            <table id="tblPrS" class="prsSearch">
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                    <th>Col3</th>
                    <th>Col4</th>
                    <th>Col5</th>
                    <th>Col6</th> 
                    <th>Col7</th> 
                    <th>Col8</th> 
                    <th>Col9</th>         
                </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate >
    <ItemTemplate >
         <tr onclick='javascript:Repeater_selectRow(this,(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1") %>));'
            style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='LightGrey'" 
             onmouseout="style.backgroundColor=''">      
            <td >
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col1")%>
            </td>
             <td >
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col2")%>
            </td>
             <td >
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col3")%>
            </td>
             <td >
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col4")%>
            </td>
             <td  >
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col5")%>
            </td>
             <td  >
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col6")%>
            </td>  
            <td  >
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col7")%>
            </td>  
            <td  >
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col8")%>
            </td>  
            <td  >
               <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Col9")%>
            </td>  

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table></div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: "click function doesn't fire" is not enough information, Any errors on the console? Did you add a breakpoint in your browser's debugger? There is another way, hook up the click with JavaScript instead of HTML attributes

Comment: No there are no errors. I tried putting breakpoint on function but no luck. Function doesn't seem to bind to on-click of row.

Answer (score 0):

There was not enough information in your guestion to post more specific answer but this might be some help for you.

I would remove the whole onclick from the tag and use jQuery like this:

```
$("tr").click(function() {

    //Do your thing

});
```